# bibliography problem - does not want to appear

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

given the following code, why biblography from .bib file does not want to appear, instead there is only the heading "references" and nothing else?
`.bib` and `.tex` file below (i have copied everything i have in my document)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage[margin=0.98in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathpazo} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\linespread{1.15} 
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalfont}
\makeatletter

\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\textbf{#1.}} 
\renewcommand{\@listI}{\itemsep=0pt} 
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{ 
    \begin{flushright} 
        {\LARGE\@title} 

        \vspace{50pt} 
        {\large\@author} 
        \\\@date %

        \vspace{40pt} 
    \end{flushright}
}


\title{\textbf{Lysine Price-Fixing Conspiracy}\\ % Title
    Causes and the aftermath} 
\author{\textsc{aaa}}

\date{\today} 


\begin{document}
    %titlepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
            \centering


            \vspace{3cm}

            {\uppercase{\Large lysine price fixing conspiracy  causes and the aftermath\par}}
            \vspace{3cm}

            {\Large Mateusz Kaczmarek\par}
            \vspace{3cm}

            {\Large \par}
            \vspace{3cm}

            {\Large \@date}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \clearpage
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \section{Abstract}
    \noindent \textit{Morbi tempor congue porta. Proin semper, leo vitae faucibus dictum, metus m}

    \newpage


    \vspace{30pt} 

    \section{Introduction}

    This 
    \section{Section Name}

    Cras gravida, est vel interdum euismod, tortor mi lobortis mi, quis 



    \section{Conclusion}

    Fusce in nibh augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis 

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First numbered list item
        \item Second numbered list item
    \end{enumerate}

    Donec luctus tincidunt mauris, non ultrices ligula aliquam id. Sed 


    \newpage

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{document}

\end{document}
```

bib file here:

```
@book{85,
    author = {autorek},
    title = {55555},
    date = {june},
}
```

I want to have something like this:
[image]
instead i have a blank page. How to fix it?

Comment: You have not `\cite`-ed the entry `85` anywhere in your document. You might also not have run the appropriate sequence of `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex`....

Comment: but i do not want to cite i want to have a listed items bibliography  that are included in the file,

Comment: @MateuszKaczmarek then use the `nocite` within your document command

Comment: where precisely? could you repost the code with necessary corrections?

Comment: You still have to "cite" these items: LaTeX is not clever enough to intuit your unexpressed/uncoded intentions.  Perhaps you want to use `\nocite{85}`.  This will populate the bibliography with the information from bibkey "85", but not `\cite` it anywhere in the document body.  Note that this still requires the command sequence I outlined above.

Comment: I've added more detailed explanation, but i will check your answer.

Comment: You did not cite any references in you document. So, you won't get any entries in the reference's section. You need to use `\cite{bib_entry_name}` to get the proper reference. Instead, if you want to show all references without citing, try `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: excuse me i tought it is more sophisticated